# ReferenceError: Preview is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting error in console when I change select option.

```
<select style="margin-bottom: 8px;" onchange="
                    if (this.value) {
                     s=$('#socials').val();
                     if (s) s+=',';
                     s+= this.value;
                     $('#socials').val(s);
                     this.value='';
                     Preview(-1);
                    }
                ">
            <option value="">Add...</option>
            <option value="amazon">Amazon</option>
            <option value="battlenet">Battle.net</option>
            <option value="blogger">Blogger</option>
            <option value="disqus">Disqus</option>
            <option value="youtube">YouTube</option>
</select>
```

i'm getting this error

> ReferenceError: Preview is not defined

I don't know how can i resolve this one. Can any please guide me where i'm doing wrong.

this is preview functions

```
function Preview(module_row) {
    if (module_row==-1) module_row=$('#row_save').val();
    else $('#row_save').val(module_row);
    css=document.getElementsByName('oneall_module[' + module_row + '][css]');
    if (css[0]) {
        css=css[0].value;
        modal=(css=='modal');
        if (css.substr(0,2)!='//') css='<?php echo substr(HTTP_SERVER,5,-6) ?>'+css;
        css=document.location.protocol+css;
        if (modal) {
            css='';
            $('#social_login_container').html('<a href="#" id="social_login_link" class="button">Social Login</a>');
        }
        w=document.getElementsByName('oneall_module[' + module_row + '][gridw]')[0].value;
        h=document.getElementsByName('oneall_module[' + module_row + '][gridh]')[0].value;
    } else {
        css=''; w=''; h=''; modal=false;
    }

    socials=$('#socials').val().split(',');


    oneall.api.plugins.social_login.build("social_login_container", {
        'providers' :  socials,
        'css_theme_uri': css,
        'grid_size_x': w,
        'grid_size_y': h,
        'modal': modal,
        'callback_uri': 'INSERT YOUR CALLBACK URI HERE'
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, where do you define the `Preview()` function?  Also, that's a lot of code to put into an inline handler like that.  Why don't you bind to the change event with jQuery?

Comment: @David i have add `Preview()` fucntion please check now, also how can i bind to the change event?

Comment: According to the error, that function isn't defined when that code is being parsed.  You've defined it here, but have you defined it on your page?  Can you demonstrate the error with an example?  As for binding events, any introductory jQuery tutorial will cover that.

Comment: @David yes this function is on same page